# c++ : discards qualifier even if the member variables are mutable

Tags: c++, inheritance, constants, mutable

I am having some issues with const/mutable and protected. Maybe these are confusing me a little bit so I will give an example.

```
class Base 
    {
       virtual void foo() const ;
       protected :
          void bar( int y ){ d_x = y } ;
       private :
         mutable int d_x ;
    }
```

So base class has as a virtual `foo`.

```
class Derived : public Base
{
   void foo() const { bar(5); }
   private :
      mutable int d_x ;
}
```

so in my derived class I have implemented `foo`, which class `bar` which then writes to the private d_x.

I would assume is fine - but compiler says :

```
passing 'Derived' as 'this' argument of bar discards qualifier.
```

Why is that? I thought by using mutable I could make my member function to be const.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From inside a const qualified function (such as `foo`), you may only call other const qualified functions. And `bar` is a not a const qualified function.

The fact `bar` only touches `d_x` is immaterial. The mutability of `d_x` only means that a const qualified member function can modify it **directly**. And formally, `bar` is allowed to modify *any* member (if they were to exist).

Comment: Interesting: I can see why the OP might object to making the bar() method const, because it changes the object. Perhaps  C++ should have a mutable qualifier for methods that affect only mutable members. // Perhaps only for documentation. Perhaps only for private or protected methods - with const methods being allowed to call const or mutable methods. Perhaps const qualification visible to the caller interface would map to (public) mutable qualification in the implementation. // Perhaps more verbose "mutable const", mutable internal, const externally visible.

Comment: @KrazyGlew - Interesting proposal. But I don't think it will be voted in. Mutable members should be the exception, not the rule.

Comment: Perhaps "const const" would be an implementation qualifier for pure read-only objects, that could be placed in true read-only-memory (ROM). Whereas "mutable const" would be an implementation qualifier that says that the object cannot be placed in ROM, although it should be treated as const for the purposes of checking user code.

Comment: I don't care if C++ won't vote on stuff like this - C++ is in many ways a dying language. I care about collecting ideas that are appropriate for the next generation of systems programming languages. // C was a good systems programming language, in many ways a portable assembler. But C and C++ never managed to truly support hardware concepts like ROM. // As for "mutable members should be exception, not the rule", consider a large (gigabyte) lookup table. Don't you want to be able to cache the most recently accessed items? Exposing the cache is bad abstraction.

Answer (score 4):

Const member function `foo` calls non-const member function `bar`. Calling `bar` requires a non-const `this`, whereas `this` is a pointer to `const` inside `foo`.

Either `bar` must be const or `foo` must be non-const.